# Maven-assembly-plugin & incremental build

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, incremental-build

It seems that the assembly plugin (or jar/war plugin) are just dumb.
They just can't figure out whenever there is just nothing to do.

A basic "Makefile" won't recompile a target if all its dependencies are older than the target.

For maven, it seems that the packaging is done "all the time" !
if I do "mvn package" and then "mvn integration-test", Maven will process the packages again and again.
Since I build some fat-standalone jars : it takes a while !

Is it also the way is works for you, or is there something broken in my configuration.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Raphaël

Answer (score 0):

In Maven exists a [Life-Cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) which is run through every time you call a phase.

```
   mvn integration-test
```

means to run all phases which are before integration-test (incl. integration-test itself) which includes in your case the package phase. Furthermore you shouldn't call integration-test cause the post-integration-test will not run in this case. You should call mvn verify instead.
The result from the above is you should simply call mvn integration-test and the package phase will run automatcially. Maven is not Make.

Comment: Fine, but still, this is a bug to me that Maven keeps packaging again a package that is up to date.

This should be the first feature of a build tool : Be incremental and only process what is necessary.
This is the case for the compile phase, that checks whether classes are up to date. I do not see why it shouldn't be the same for packaging.

Plus, there are some situation where I would like to launch again my integration test suite, without compiling or packaging anything : For example, when I have changed my test data on a remote test-SQL server.

Comment: Hm..You wrote you changed your test data on the remote SQL server ...but why don't you put that data into your maven project and let do that through the integration test...The idea is to do build (and testing) automatically without manual steps. On the other hand it's not that simple to see if a package must be updated or not and furthermore some package format don't support updating of files inside the package. On other thing which comes to my mind is: You have large jar's ..may be you should think about smaller modules instead.